# How to get typoscript setup in a scheduler/cron script?

Tags: typo3

I need to get the extension typoscript setup in schedular script.

I am using typo3 v 4.5.

My schedular script looks like this.

```
class tx_myext_scheduler extends tx_scheduler_Task { 
    public function execute() {
        //here i need to get typoscript setup
    }
}
```

and my extension setup looks like this.

```
plugin.tx_myext_pi1{
    listView{
        file.height = 216c
    }
}
```

In schedualr script I need to get the file.height value.
How to do that ?

Currently i tried this without success

```
$pObj = $GLOBALS['TSFE'];
$conf = $pObj->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_myext_pi1.'];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `TSFE` is only available in the frontend, so have to initialize it yourself (that consumes some resources!). You can create it like that in scheduler: ([source](http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/110639/?show=1))

```
$GLOBALS['TT'] = new t3lib_timeTrackNull;
$GLOBALS['TSFE'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_fe', $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'], 2, 0);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_pageSelect');
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->init(TRUE);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine = '';
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRootLine(1, '');
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();
```

or in an eID script: ([source](https://www.zoe.vc/2008/typoscript-auslesen/))

```
require_once(PATH_tslib.'class.tslib_fe.php');
require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_page.php');
$temp_TSFEclassName = t3lib_div::makeInstanceClassName('tslib_fe');
$GLOBALS['TSFE'] = new $temp_TSFEclassName($TYPO3_CONF_VARS, $pid, 0, true);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->connectToDB();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->initFEuser();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->determineId();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->getCompressedTCarray();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();
```

or in a backend module: ([source](https://www.zoe.vc/2008/typoscript-auslesen/))

```
function loadTypoScriptForBEModule($extKey) {
    require_once(PATH_t3lib . 'class.t3lib_page.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib . 'class.t3lib_tstemplate.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib . 'class.t3lib_tsparser_ext.php');
    list($page) = t3lib_BEfunc::getRecordsByField('pages', 'pid', 0);
    $pageUid = intval($page['uid']);
    $sysPageObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_pageSelect');
    $rootLine = $sysPageObj->getRootLine($pageUid);
    $TSObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_tsparser_ext');
    $TSObj->tt_track = 0;
    $TSObj->init();
    $TSObj->runThroughTemplates($rootLine);
    $TSObj->generateConfig();
    return $TSObj->setup['plugin.'][$extKey . '.'];
}
```

If you have missing class errors somewhere, maybe you have to add some requires.

Comment: Hi, I tried the first way you specified above, but its giving error
Fatal error: Call to a member function push() on a non-object in /home/src/typo3_src-4.5.10/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_fe.php on line 2079

Comment: I guess you have to do some debugging on your own then. Have a look in the stacktrace, check the file on line given and see which object is expected there. It is possible, that something more needs to be initialized. Possibly the code you need is included in the two other examples.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is perfect if the page is in standard mode, but doesn't work if the page is a Draft:

```
function loadTypoScriptForBEModule($extKey) {
    require_once(PATH_t3lib . 'class.t3lib_page.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib . 'class.t3lib_tstemplate.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib . 'class.t3lib_tsparser_ext.php');
    list($page) = t3lib_BEfunc::getRecordsByField('pages', 'pid', 0);
    $pageUid = intval($page['uid']);
    $sysPageObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_pageSelect');
    $rootLine = $sysPageObj->getRootLine($pageUid);
    $TSObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_tsparser_ext');
    $TSObj->tt_track = 0;
    $TSObj->init();
    $TSObj->runThroughTemplates($rootLine);
    $TSObj->generateConfig();
    return $TSObj->setup['plugin.'][$extKey . '.'];
}
```